# Will my Windows OS be kept if I install Ubuntu

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I use Windows 8 Consumer Preview, and since it is going to expire, I wondered if I can keep Windows 8 when I install Ubuntu or not, because I want to still use Windows 8 as well as Ubuntu.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

You can choose to run both Windows and Ubuntu together, on the same machine. This is called Dual-booting.

The easiest and safest way is to create an empty drive in windows, delete it to get free space, and install Ubuntu using Live CD or Live USB, choosing the option 'Install alongside Windows'. The setup will automatically install into the free space created by you.

Even if you directly boot from cd without creating free space, The installer will attempt to resize your windows partition and will install alongside. But there is one in a thousand chance that this may cause data loss, since NTFS file system is not effectively manipulated from Ubuntu (yet), I suggest making free space from windows before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can . after inserting the LIVE CD , moving with regular steps , stop at this . [image]

so there 1st and 3rd options are good for you to keep windows and install Ubuntu .Remember **dont touch the WINDOWS partition** while doing the installation process  and remaining all are same as a normal installation process .

All the best .

But as our one of the answer saying its not possible with win-8 , i too heard about win-8 is going to behave like as he said but give a try my friend ,we loss nothing with a try .

Comment: it works perfectly, atleast for now. we need not worry until win8 is officially released. and there is still a chance that it might never be implemented. UEFI is much debated thing these days.